# Function Composition Proofs

Tags: functions

There will be A,B,C,D sets and the following functions $ f:A \rightarrow B, g:B \rightarrow C, h: C\rightarrow D $ 
Prove or disprove that if $h\circ g \circ f$ is  bijection then $g:$ is 1-1 or $g:$ is surjective.

I understand that $g$ do not have to be 1-1, but I am finding it hard to write down a formal proof using the definition of 1-1 and surjective.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a formal proof. A counter example is fine.

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 : x \mapsto (x,0)$, $g: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2: (x,y) \mapsto (x,0)$, and $h: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R : (x,y) \mapsto x$.
Then $h \circ g \circ f$ is a bijection as $h \circ g \circ f$ is just the identity function on $\mathbb R$, but $g$ is not 1-1 as $g(1,1) = g(1,0)$.

If you find a counter example for surjectivity i.e. a $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ such that $(x,y)$ does not lie in the image of $g$ you will have disproved the statement.